# Failing to install npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install `node` on OSX like this:

```
brew install node
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
==> Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/node-0.12.7.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7 --without-npm --without-s
==> make install
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [/private/tmp/node20160118-13255-1k2k8lz/node-v0.12.7/out/Release/openssl-cli] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [node] Error 2
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
```

I uninstalled `macports` but the error persists.

How can I install `node` and `npm` on a Mac?

Comment: try to download from site https://nodejs.org/en/download/ a mac pkg. It will install both node and npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available options for Mac OS X:

- Download [NodeJS Installer for Mac](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#macos)
- [Via package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#osx):

  - Homebrew: `brew install node`
  - MacPorts: `port install nodejs`
  - pkgsrc: `pkgin -y install nodejs`

---

cURL and execute with bash:

```
curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-${VERSION:-$(wget -qO- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | sed -nE 's|.*>node-(.*)\.pkg</a>.*|\1|p')}.pkg" > "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" && sudo installer -store -pkg "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" -target "/"
```

Comment: Your link to the Installer for Mac points to an old version.  Rather link to the download page itself so users can always download the latest version.  Download: https://nodejs.org/en/